# Which Symfony version to choose?

Tags: symfony

I am wondering why support for Symfony 3.2 will end on July 2017 while Symfony 2.8 will on November 2018?

I will start a new project and I am little lost about what version of symfony to download. The last version or an old version that has more support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony 2.8 has long term support (LTS). This means it will be supported up to four years after its release. Since the release was November 2015 the support will continue until 2019. 2.8 will be the last version of Symfony 2, wich means that Symfony 2 will be end of life in November 2018.

Symfony 3.2 is a "normal" version without LTS. The next LTS version of Symfony 3 will be 3.4 which is scheduled to be released in 9/2017, which means that Symfony 3 will be end of life in 2021.

You can find the complete release schedule including Symfony 4 at this link. [Symfony Release Schedule](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#version-history)

TL;DR: Use Symfony 3.x, it will be supported 3 more years than Symfony 2.

EDIT: The symfony website mentions different values for the number of years a lts version is supported. The page I linked mentions four years, so I corrected the numbers above. The three years I mentioned in the original post can be found here. [version 2.8 roadmap](http://symfony.com/roadmap?version=2.8)

Comment: SF 3 is the way to go. 2.8 has backwards compatibility with older versions, but those are removed in 3.x. There is no reason to use 2.8 for a new project. Upgrading later from 2.8 to 3.x will be troublesome.

Comment: lts is four years so eol for s3 is 11/2021

Comment: No question here, the Symfony3 choice is obvious, you avoid a migration which always take time. (even if from 2.8 to 3.x it shouldn't be very hard)

Comment: Please note, LTS versions receive 3 years *maintainence support* and 4 years *security support*. After Nov 2018, only security leaks will be fixed in Symfoy 2.8. After Nov 2019, there will no longer be any release of Symfony 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this release schedule](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html#schedule). Version 2.8 is part of the Long Term Support. You could go with version 2.8, but it makes more sense to use the latest version of 3.2, and then use `composer update` to update your project. Version 3.4 should be coming out soon.

You have a choice **not** to update your Symfony version if you don't want to. I'm not sure if that addresses your question?

Answer (score 1):

I would choose Symfony 3.2, it will be easier to upgrade to the 3.4 release which is a long time support version (2021).
[Check here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/community/releases.html)